# how do you escape an nmake command line inside cmake?

Tags: windows, cmake, zlib, nmake

I am trying to build zlib on windows as a dependency in my cmake project.

I have come up with the following which works fine:

```
    file(WRITE ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zlib.nmake
            AS=ml64\n
            LOC="-DASMV -DASMINF -DNDEBUG -I."\n
            OBJA="inffasx64.obj gvmat64.obj inffas8664.obj"\n
            -f win32/Makefile.msc\n
            zlib.lib\n)
    ExternalProject_Add(
            zlib
            GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/kyotov/zlib.git
            GIT_TAG mt
            PREFIX ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}
            CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
            BUILD_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E chdir <SOURCE_DIR> nmake @${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/zlib.nmake
            INSTALL_COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy <SOURCE_DIR>/zlib.h <INSTALL_DIR>/install/include/zlib.h
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy <SOURCE_DIR>/zconf.h <INSTALL_DIR>/install/include/zconf.h
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy <SOURCE_DIR>/zlib.lib <INSTALL_DIR>/install/lib/zlib.lib
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy <SOURCE_DIR>/zlib.pdb <INSTALL_DIR>/install/lib/zlib.pdb
    )
```

I would really prefer if I can inline the call to nmake and not have to resort to passing @ parameter.

I spent about 15-30 minutes trying to escape the double quotes in various ways but could not get it done.

Google did not teach me anything either...

Anybody has any smart ideas?